# Dynamic MatTabBar Nav with MatMenu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a component that will render out a mat-tab-nav-bar for my application dynamically. My problem is that some of the nav items also require a Mat Menu. I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to code this as efficiently as possible. Here's and example of the payload I'm consuming to render the nav bar (please note *menuItems* in an optional observable to load the menu items.

```json
pages: NavbarPage[] = [
    { 
      hasMenu: false,
      label: 'Page Uno',
      pageType: 0,
      path: '/uno',
      menuItems: null
    },
    { 
      hasMenu: true,
      label: 'Page Dos',
      pageType: 1,
      path: '/dos',
      menuItems: menuItems$
    },
    { 
      hasMenu: false,
      label: 'Page Tres',
      pageType: 2,
      path: '/tres',
      menuItems: null
    },
    { 
      hasMenu: true,
      label: 'Page Cuatro',
      pageType: 3,
      path: '/cuatro',
      menuItems: anotherMenuItemsObservable$
    }
  ];
```

I can't figure out how the create the mat-menus for only the two items that need a mat-menu, and **not** for the others since I'm also using an *ngFor. Am I missing something obvious? Any assistance or explanations would be appreciated! One of my failed attempts is below:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-align-tabs="center">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let page of pages">     
<ng-container *ngIf="page.hasMenu === true">
      <a mat-tab-link routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
  (click)="navigate(page)" [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">{{page.label}}
  <mat-icon *ngIf="page.isMenu">expand_more</mat-icon></a>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="page.hasMenu === false">
      <a mat-tab-link routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [routerLink]="page.path" [active]="rla.isActive">{{page.label}}</a>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</nav>
```

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more ? after you have checked `hasMenu` then what are you doing ?